# Second activity will not launch in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here are my imports

```
package com.example.itbachelor.hangman;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
```

Here are the declarations i did next for this class

```
public  class Noose extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView imageView2;
Button playButton2;
TextView textView6;
EditText letterText;
int count;

int imageArray[] = {R.drawable.noose, R.drawable.head, R.drawable.utorso, R.drawable.ltorso, R.drawable.arms, R.drawable.legs, R.drawable.dead};
String food1[] = {"B", "A", "S", "I", "L"};
String food2[] = {"O", "L", "I", "V", "E"};
String food3[] = {"C", "H", "I", "V", "E"};
String food4[] = {"G", "R", "A", "P", "E"};
String food5[] = {"L", "E", "M", "O", "N"};
Button buttons[]=new Button[5];
```

Then here is my program for this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noose);
    textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    letterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letterText);
    playButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton2);
    playButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondButton);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdButton);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fourthButton);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fifthButton);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(5);
    imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[0]);
```

This is a hangman app so I wanted to start with just 5 words to compare

```
    switch (n) {
        case 0:

            do {
                View.OnClickListener add = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= food1.length - 1; i++) {
                            if (letterText.getText().toString().equals(food1[i])) {
                                System.out.print("Correct");
                                buttons[i].setText(food1[i]);
                            } else {
                                System.out.print("Incorrect!");
                                count++;
                                imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            while (count < 6);
            break;
```

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner at this

```
 case 1:
            do {
                View.OnClickListener add = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= food2.length - 1; i++) {
                            if        (letterText.getText().toString().equals(food2[i])) {
                            System.out.print("Correct");
                            buttons[i].setText(food2[i]);
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("Incorrect!");
                            count++;
                            imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

        }
        while (count < 6);
        break;
    case 2:
        do {
            View.OnClickListener add = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= food3.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (letterText.getText().toString().equals(food3[i])) {
                            System.out.print("Correct");
                            buttons[i].setText(food3[i]);
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("Incorrect!");
                            count++;
                            imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
        }
        while (count < 6);
        break;
    case 3:
        do {
            View.OnClickListener add = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= food4.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (letterText.getText().toString().equals(food4[i])) {
                            System.out.print("Correct");
                            buttons[i].setText(food4[i]);
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("Incorrect!");
                            count++;
                            imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
        }
        while (count < 6);
        break;
    case 4:
        do {
            View.OnClickListener add = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= food5.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (letterText.getText().toString().equals(food5[i])) {
                            System.out.print("Correct");
                            buttons[i].setText(food5[i]);
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("Incorrect!");
                            count++;
                            imageView2.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

        }
        while (count < 6);
        break;

  }
}
```

My program was at least switching the pages, but now it won't.  Not sure where I went wrong

Comment: Please actually ask a question. What specifically are you trying to do and/or what do you expect to happen, and how does that differ from what's actually happening? Include code snippets that are _relevant_ to your question instead of posting all of your code; if you can't narrow down a specific area of code, then you haven't done enough debugging on your own yet.

Comment: please do some effort first

Comment: As I stated before, I am pretty new to this, no need to be rude, you could be polite.

Comment: I have spent several hours trying to debug the program.  It stopped being able to instantiate after I added the lines

Comment: declaring the arrays and the buttons. I just wanted someone to give some advice who may be able to look at a few lines of code and be able to guide me to what I may be doing wrong

Comment: the second activity that I have posted above will not instantiate now.

Comment: Even though I also didn't understand the question. If you're talking about a second activity, then I expect a piece of code saying startActivity or an Intent.